# Сумма элементов списка, расположенных между первым и последним положительным элементами

Tags: python, list, список, for

Задание: в списке целых, заполненном случайными числами вычислить сумму элементов, находящихся между первым и последним положительными элементами. Столкнулась с такой проблемой: первую часть задания я сделала (по нахождению чётных элементов), а вторую не могу (при добавлении нового массива происходит ошибка). Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
import random
randlist = []
lst = []
for i in range(3):
    n = random.randint(-10,30)
    randlist.append(n)
print(randlist)
positive = 0
for i in range(len(randlist)):
    if randlist[i] > 0:
        positive+= randlist[i]
print (positive)
for i in range(positive[1],positive[-1]):
    lst += positive
print (lst)
```

Comment: Можете уточнить, какое задание, какие входные, на данный вопрос очень трудно ответить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: То есть, для массива вида: [-1, -2, 4, 5, 6 ,7 8, -15, -16 9, -1] ответ будет  8? Я правильно понял или сами границы положительных чисел не включаются ?

Comment: По- идее, начало массива - 4, конец - 9. Т-е, сумма чисел 5 6 7 8

Comment: А почему отрицательные числа не суммируете, судя по вашим словам? В задании про это ничего не сказано.

Comment: В задании написано;  "вычислить сумму элементов, находящихся между первым и последним ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНЫМИ элементами".

Comment: Ну вот я и не пойму, почему -15, -16 в сумму не входят, они же между первым положительным 4 и последним положительным 9.

Comment: Если происходит ошибка - её нужно прочитать и понять, почему происходит. Зачем тут второй список?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import dropwhile
from random import choices

data = choices(range(-10, 10), k=20)
print(data)
print(
    sum(
        list(
            dropwhile(
                lambda x: x <= 0, 
                reversed(
                    list(
                        dropwhile(
                            lambda x: x <= 0, 
                            data
                        )
                    )[1:]
                )
            )
        )[1:]
    )
)
```

> Если считать 0 положительным числом нужно исправить сравнение в обеих лямбдах

---

```latex
[-3, 6, -7, -10, -10, -2, -3, -4, 0, 3, 9, 3, -2, -9, -4, -2, 7, 6, -1, 8]
-26
```

> Материал по теме
> [choices](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-random-python/funktsija-random-choices/)
> [dropwhile](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-itertools-python/funktsija-dropwhile-modulja-itertools/)

---

#### UPD -> для наглядности

```py
from itertools import dropwhile
from random import choices

data = choices(range(-10, 10), k=10)

print(f'{data = }')
# data = [-9, 5, -1, 1, 2, 3, -2, 4, -4, 4]

cut_left = list(
    dropwhile(
        lambda x: x <= 0,
        data
    )
)[1:]

print(f'{cut_left = }')
# cut_left = [-1, 1, 2, 3, -2, 4, -4, 4]

desired = list(
    dropwhile(
        lambda x: x <= 0,
        reversed(
            cut_left
        )
    )
)[1:]

print(f'{desired = }')

# desired = [-4, 4, -2, 3, 2, 1, -1]
# !!! Здесь список в обатном порядке
# Но нам на это пофиг ;-)

print(
    f'{sum(desired) = }'
)
# sum(desired) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос звучит так "Сумма элементов списка, расположенных между первым и последним положительным элементами", то судя по каментам, задача понята неверно:

эта сумма не должна включать границы "первым и последним", раз явно не указано

эта сумма любых элементов, а не только положительных

```
lt = [-1, 1, 3, -4, 4, -5, -6, 9, -5, -9, ]
s1 = s2 = 0
for s1, a in enumerate(lt):
    if a > 0:
        break  # определить индекс первого положительного элемента
for s2, a in enumerate(reversed(lt)):
    if a > 0:
        break  # определить индекс последнего положительного элемента
s = sum(lt[s1+1: -s2-1])  # взять сумму между индексами
print(s)
```